# Unable to import Python file in VSCode Julia notebook

Tags: julia

I'm trying to import a Python file containing a single function into my Julia notebook in VSCode.

The file is called `helloPython.py` and contains a single function called `helloFromPython`.

It contains the following code.

```
def helloFromPython():
    print("Hello Julia, it's me Python!")
```

It is located in the same directory as my notebook file.

My first cell looks as follows.

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("PyCall")
Pkg.build("PyCall")
using PyCall
```

Importing inbuilt Python functions works as expected, e.g.

```
math = pyimport("math")
math.sin(math.pi / 4)
```

Defining and calling Python code on the fly also works as expected, for example

```
begin
    py"""
def f(x):
    return x**3
"""
    f = py"f"
end

f(2) # prints 8
```

However, importing my local Python file does not work. My cell looks as follows.

```
pushfirst!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")."path"), "")
x = pyimport("helloPython")
x.helloFromPython()
```

There is no error message. The cell executes successfully and that's it.

I've tried the same using the inbuild terminal in VSCode starting the Julia command prompt and it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** @alex338207 had a good idea here, so I'm updating my question.

Writing to a file works. Here is a minimal working example. The file `helloPython.py` contains the following code.

```
def helloFromPython():
    f = open("test.txt", "a")
    f.write("Hello Julia!")
    f.close()
```

Calling the above in VSCode as describe above, works as expected. A file is created with the provided content "Hello Julia!".

However, returning stuff doesn't work. Here is another example.

```
def helloFromPython():
    return "Hello Julia!"
```

Calling the above yields to the output `nothing`.

I've updated my issue on [Github](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2700).

Comment: this looks like a bug to me. I was able to replicate it. Perhaps opening an issue of project repository could be a good idea?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel thanks for your quick response. I've opened an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2700).

Comment: Does it work when the python code writes to a file? Maybe the python's stdout is not captured correctly.

Comment: @alex338207 I'm sorry for my late response. It works with writing the output to a file. I'll add an example in my question and update the issue on GitHub. Thank you, this was a good idea!

Comment: It is interesting though, that returning stuff doesn't work at all.